# How does one override the OnShown Event of a form when creating a form programmatically?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a sound to play when a form is first shown (rather like a standard message box does for want of a better example).  If using a standard form added through the designer I would generally do this by overriding the standard onshown event and then go on to call MyBase.OnShown(e)

The problem I've hit now is that the form is being created programmatically (Dim myForm as new Form etc) and as such I seem not to be able to use AddHandler to override this event.  I don't doubt that I'm doing this in entirely the wrong way, but I'd appreciate any advice that can be offered.  I would prefer advice from the perspective of VB.net, but I can just about muddle through in C#.

Answer (score 1):

`Form.OnShown` is not an event.  Rather, it is a method of the `Form` class which raises the form's `Shown` event.  Here's the MSDN article that explains the `OnShown` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown.aspx

When you are making a derived class by using the form designer, you can override the `OnShown` method, but when you are simply accessing a form through its public interface, you need to use the `Shown` event instead.  You can add an event handler for that event like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As Form1 = New Form1()
    AddHandler f.Shown, AddressOf f_Shown
    f.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub f_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, and @Lars.  Iought to have realised this, but it turned into one of those can't see the wood for trees type of problem.  Thank you both for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the form doesn't exist in code, you would actually have to call the event then.

Try writing out the showing code first:

```
Public Sub form_Showing(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  // play sound
End Sub
```

then when you create your form, you add the handler of the event:

```
Dim f As New Form
AddHandler f.Shown, AddressOf form_Showing
f.Show()
```